# Unable to create shadows around button and UIView

Tags: ios, swift, button, view, shadow

I added in my app a button and set it with this code:

```
locationButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7
locationButton.clipsToBounds = true
locationButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
locationButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
locationButton.layer.shadowRadius = 3
locationButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
locationButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

I made the same thing with an UIView

```
profileView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
profileView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
profileView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
profileView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
profileView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The button appears with no shadows at all, while the View has shadows not around the borders but around the elements inside itself.

Comment: When you set layer.maskToBounds = true, then any sublayers of the layer that extend outside its boundaries will be clipped to those boundaries. Since shadow exists outside of the boundary so it will be clipped to the boundary. You can opt to create an inner containerView pinned to the edges of the parent view. The shadow is applied to the parent view’s layer, while the rounded corners are applied to the containerView. Then, just add all content to the containerView and be on your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code

```
button.layer.masksToBounds = false
button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
button.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

[image]